# How to aggregate the quantity in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to find the sum of the quantities, count of txns, sum of dollar_value_us and calculation of margin for both the split and the single transactions.

below is the link to the database which I have created:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=97be115a173cd7dbdb3e4a6a6ed35a16

I already have this query to find the count of transactions which are single and split:

```
select count(distinct case when is_split = 'Yes' then transaction_number end) as split,
  count(distinct case when is_split = 'No' then transaction_number end) as single
from (
  select td.transaction_number, td.sku,
    case when count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number) > 0
         then 'Yes'
         else 'No'
    end as has_pod_sku,
    case when count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number) > 0
         and  count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number)
                < count(*) over (partition by td.transaction_number)
         then 'Yes'
         else 'No'
    end as is_split
  from transaction_detail_mv td
  left join pod_sku ps on ps.sku = td.sku
)
where has_pod_sku = 'Yes';
```

I am using the below code for aggregation:

```
    select count(distinct case when is_split = 'Yes' then transaction_number end) as split,
  count(distinct case when is_split = 'No' then transaction_number end) as single,
  sum(case when is_split = 'Yes' then quantity end) as quantity_sp,
  sum(case when is_split = 'No' then quantity end) as quantity_sn,
  sum(case when is_split = 'Yes' then dollar_value_us end) as spend_sp,
  sum(case when is_split = 'No' then dollar_value_us end) as spend_sn,
  count(distinct case when is_split = 'Yes' then individual_id end) as indiv_sp,
  count(distinct case when is_split = 'No' then individual_id end) as indiv_sn,
  sum(case when is_split = 'Yes' then (DOLLAR_VALUE_US-(COGS*quantity)) end) as MARGIN_sp,
  sum(case when is_split = 'No' then (DOLLAR_VALUE_US-(COGS*quantity)) end) as MARGIN_sN

from (
      select td.transaction_number, td.sku,
        case when count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number) > 0
             then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end as has_pod_sku,
        case when count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number) > 0
             and  count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number)
                    < count(*) over (partition by td.transaction_number)
             then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end as is_split
      from transaction_detail_mv td
      left join pod_sku ps on ps.sku = td.sku
    )
    where has_pod_sku = 'Yes';
```

I am looking for an output like below:

[image]

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I updated the quesion @MarcinJ

Comment: if that's your expected output, why it doesn't mach with the columns of your query?

Comment: @SomiyaL: please show us the content of the expected results, not just its structure.

Comment: @GMB I updated the output. my column headers are different from the column header in sql code because I made this output format on excel.

Comment: Where is COGS coming from?

Comment: @MarcinJ that is a separate column header in the data base for which I provided the link

Comment: That's the issue, it's not in the link. Neither in `transaction_detail_mv` nor in `POD_SKU`.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=97be115a173cd7dbdb3e4a6a6ed35a16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of aggregating per transaction type (Split/Single) in column, `GROUP BY` the transaction type:

```
SELECT v.transaction_type
     , COUNT(DISTINCT v.transaction_number) AS transaction_count
     , COUNT(DISTINCT v.individual_id) AS customer_count
     , SUM(v.quantity) AS units
     , SUM(v.dollar_value_us) AS sales
     , SUM(v.dollar_value_us - v.cogs * v.quantity) AS profit
  FROM (SELECT td.transaction_number, td.sku, td.quantity, td.dollar_value_us, td.individual_id, td.cogs,
               CASE 
                 WHEN COUNT(ps.sku) OVER (PARTITION BY td.transaction_number) > 0
                 THEN 'Yes'
                 ELSE 'No'
               END AS has_pod_sku,
               CASE  
                 WHEN COUNT(ps.sku) OVER (PARTITION BY td.transaction_number) > 0
                  AND COUNT(ps.sku) OVER (PARTITION BY td.transaction_number)
                    < COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY td.transaction_number)
                 THEN 'Split'
                 ELSE 'Single'
               END AS transaction_type
          FROM transaction_detail_mv td
          LEFT OUTER
          JOIN pod_sku ps on ps.sku = td.sku
     ) v
 WHERE has_pod_sku = 'Yes'
 GROUP BY v.transaction_type
```

[Working query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=07e5283cb4c06e4260ff266ff5d36f1a).

Comment: so basically my split+single should = total (which is if I do a simple query from the transaction_detail_mv table) but it does not match if I add the dollar_value_ud of split and single

Comment: It shouldn't, you're filtering only for transactions with SKUs for which there is an entry in POD_SKU (at least one entry in case of split transactions), and not all of them have them. For example SKU 983636 does not exist in POD_SKU so transaction 975 will be excluded.

Comment: but it should match the total if I join it to the pod_table right?

Comment: No. If you simply inner join transactions to pod_sku, you'll only get the exact transactions that have matching SKU items in that table. So for example in a split transaction 567 you have SKUs 903633 (in POD_SKU) and 123767 (not in) - you'll only get the amount for 903633. What our query does is different - it checks if any of the SKUs exist in that table (and 903633 does) and then aggregates the whole transaction, including the SKUs that are not in POD_SKU.